# Count Points in Polygon and write result to (Geo)Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, geopandas

I want to count how many points there are per Polygon

```
# Credits of this code go to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69642668/the-indices-of-the-two-geoseries-are-different-understanding-indices/69644010#69644010
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import geopandas as gpd
import shapely.geometry
import requests

# source some points and polygons
# fmt: off
dfp = pd.read_html("https://www.latlong.net/category/cities-235-15.html")[0]
dfp = gpd.GeoDataFrame(dfp, geometry=dfp.loc[:,["Longitude", "Latitude",]].apply(shapely.geometry.Point, axis=1))
res = requests.get("https://opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/69dc11c7386943b4ad8893c45648b1e1_0.geojson")
df_poly = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_features(res.json())
# fmt: on
```

Now I `sjoin` the two. I use `df_poly` first, in order to add the points `dfp` to the `GeoDataframe` `df_poly`.

```
df_poly.sjoin(dfp)
```

Now I want to count how many `points` there are per `polygon`.
I thought

```
df_poly.sjoin(dfp).groupby('OBJECTID').count()
```

But that does not add a `column` to the `GeoDataframe` `df_poly` with the `count` of each `group`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add one of the columns from the output of `count()` back into the original DataFrame using merge. I have used the geometry column and renamed it to `n_points`:

```
df_poly.merge(
    df_poly.sjoin(
        dfp
    ).groupby(
        'OBJECTID'
    ).count().geometry.rename(
        'n_points'
    ).reset_index())
```

Comment: This answer works but could you explain it more to people who are looking to gain understanding?

Answer (score 2):

This is a follow on to this question [The indices of the two GeoSeries are different - Understanding Indices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69642668/the-indices-of-the-two-geoseries-are-different-understanding-indices/69644010#69644010)

- **right_index** of spatial join gives index of polygon as polygon was on right of spatial join
- hence the series  `gpd.sjoin(dfp, df_poly).groupby("index_right").size().rename("points")` can then be simply joined to the polygon **GeoDataFrame** to give how many points were found
- note `how="left"` to ensure it's a left join, not an inner join.  Any polygons with no points with have `NaN` you may want to `fillna(0)` in this case.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import geopandas as gpd
import shapely.geometry
import requests

# source some points and polygons
# fmt: off
dfp = pd.read_html("https://www.latlong.net/category/cities-235-15.html")[0]
dfp = pd.concat([dfp,dfp]).reset_index(drop=True)
dfp = gpd.GeoDataFrame(dfp, geometry=dfp.loc[:,["Longitude", "Latitude",]].apply(shapely.geometry.Point, axis=1))
res = requests.get("https://opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/69dc11c7386943b4ad8893c45648b1e1_0.geojson")
df_poly = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_features(res.json())
# fmt: on

df_poly.join(
    gpd.sjoin(dfp, df_poly).groupby("index_right").size().rename("points"),
    how="left",
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Building on both your own answer and Rob Raymond's answer, I tried to create a more generic one as a function that:

- keeps the polygons containing no points and set their count to 0
- has some safeguards on the index of the polygons dataframe
- contains many (too much?) comments

Here it is:

```py
def count_points_in_polygons(points, polygons, polygon_id, new_column="points_count"):

    # Save the index to restore it later
    original_index = polygons.index

    # Ensures polygon_id is not the index but a column
    if original_index.name == polygon_id:
        polygons = polygons.reset_index()

    # Count points in polygons
    points_in_polygon = (
        # Spatial join associates points and polygons that intersects each other
        polygons.sjoin(
            points,
            how="inner",  # Only keep points that matches a polygon
        )
        .groupby(polygon_id)  # Group points by polygons
        .size()  # Get number of points
        .rename(new_column)  # Name your column as you want it to appear in polygons
    )

    # Add count series to the polygons dataframe
    polygons = (
        polygons.set_index(polygon_id)  # Ensures the index is the same as points_in_polygons
        .join(
            points_in_polygon,
            how="left",  # Keep polygons containing no points
        )
        .fillna({new_column: 0})  # Fill NaN with 0
    )

    if original_index.name != polygon_id:
        # Avoids duplicating polygon_id as column and index
        polygons = polygons.reset_index()

    polygons = polygons.set_index(original_index) # Restore the original index

    return polygons
```

In your specific case it could be called like this:

```py
count_points_in_polygons(dfp, df_poly, "OBJECTID", new_column="n_points")
```

Answer (score 0):

Building on the answere Fergus McClean provided, this can even be done in less code:

```
df_poly.merge(df_poly.sjoin(dfp).groupby('OBJECTID').size().rename('n_points').reset_index())
```

However, the method (`.join()`) proposed by Rob Raymond to combine the two `dataframes` keeps the entries that have no count.